# Agricola Online

Tags: agricola, online

Does anyone know of any online (or iPhone, iPad, PC, Xbox, PS2, or PS3 for that matter!) versions of Agricola - or know if any are in the works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[play-agricola.com](http://play-agricola.com/)

14 playable boards, images directly from the game.  All expansions, and the site owners appear to have a hot line to the designer.

Answer (score 6):

An iPad/iPhone-version is coming this winter:

http://ipadboardgames.org/2011/schedule-of-upcoming-games/

Edit:

The iOS app is out:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/agricola/id561521557?mt=8

Answer (score 4):

http://boiteajeux.net

Added Agricola on 28/07/11. Very well made. Board and card scans are from the French edition, but tool tips are in English.

Comment: That is excellent, best I've seen so far!  Just did a quick solo game and got 64 points...

Answer (score 3):

This site was AWESOME: http://www.agricolaonline.com/

Until the guy had to take it down.

play-agricola.com was around before agricola online, but its interface is pretty atrocious and you still have to manually reload all the bits and everything.  I'd rather not play or just play the physical game than use play-agricola.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can now also play online on Board Game Arena (BGA): https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=agricola

Currently in beta but will probably be released soon.